# Executing a method every x seconds with different parameters inside a loop in JAVA

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, timertask

How to run a method periodically with different parameters inside a loop?

```
Iteration 1 : obj.process(index1)
wait 5 seconds...
Iteration 2: obj.process(index2)
wait 5 seconds...
Iteration 3: obj.process(index3)
wait 5 seconds...
and so on...
```

Specifically, my goal is to repetitively run a method, and the next iteration needs to wait X seconds, and the next iteration also needs to wait X seconds and so on.

My example code, and it's wrong and starts all ***obj.process(index)*** at almost the same time:

```
Timer time = new Timer();           
for (final String index : indeces) {
        int counter = 0;            
        time.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                indexMap.put(index, obj.process(index));
            }
        }, delay);
        counter++;
        if (counter > indeces.size())
            System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: so you want to iterate a loop suppose 10 times and each time you want to pass different parameters and wait for few seconds. is it u want??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is running in it's own thread, the following minimal example can be useful:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[][] parameters ={ new String[]{"HELLO", "WORLD"},
                             new Integer[]{1,2,3},
                             new Double[]{0.1, 0.9, 5.3}
                            };
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

            doSomething(parameters[i]);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void doSomething(Object[] objects) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objects));
}
```

In Java 8, a possible solution could be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[][] parameters ={ new String[]{"HELLO", "WORLD"},
                             new Integer[]{1,2,3},
                             new Double[]{0.1, 0.9, 5.3}
                            };
    Arrays.stream(parameters).forEachOrdered(p -> doSomething(p));
}

private static void doSomething(Object[] objects) {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objects));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a single `Timer` for all objects. Make the `run` method process a single object. Have the `run` method re-schedule the `TimerTask` (i.e., `this`) if there are more objects to process.

With such solution you don't need the loop, the timer just needs to be set up once.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me:

```
public class TestClass {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] indeces = new String[] {"one", "two", "three"};

        long delay = 0;



        Timer time = new Timer();           
        for (final String index : indeces) {
                int counter = 0;        
                System.out.println("index-->" + delay);
                time.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    Map indexMap = new HashMap();

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        indexMap.put(index, index);
                        System.out.println("index-->" + index);

                    }
                }, delay);
                counter++;
                delay = delay + 5000; // Increase delay by 5 secs
                if (counter > indeces.length)
                    System.exit(0);
            }       

    }
```

Basically I have incremented the delay by 5 secs for every Timer Task